# Remove breakLine between td in sourceCode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Public Function GenerateHtmlReport(ByVal ResultDataset As System.Data.DataSet) As String Implements IValidation.GenerateHtmlReport
        Dim _StrBuil As New StringBuilder()
        Dim clsHtmlBuilder As New HtmlBuilder()
        Try
            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(2) & clsHtmlBuilder.AddHr())
            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(3) & clsHtmlBuilder.TextBig(ResultDataset.DataSetName))
            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(5) & clsHtmlBuilder.AddLineBreak)

            For Each _Tbl As DataTable In ResultDataset.Tables
                If _Tbl Is Nothing OrElse _Tbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then Continue For
                _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(8) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTable())

                'set Table Header
                'set Table Name

                _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(15) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartH4())
                _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(20) & _Tbl.TableName)
                _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(15) & clsHtmlBuilder.EndH4())
                _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(25) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTableRow())

                'set Column Name
                For Each _col As DataColumn In _Tbl.Columns
                    _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(35) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTableHeader())
                    _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(45) & _col.ColumnName)
                    _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(35) & clsHtmlBuilder.EndTableHeader())

                Next
                _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(25) & clsHtmlBuilder.EndTableRow())

                'set Table Rows
                For Each _dr As DataRow In _Tbl.Rows
                    _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(25) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTableRow())
                    For Each _col As DataColumn In _Tbl.Columns
                        If (Space(45) & _col.ColumnName = "Result") Then
                            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(35) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTableCell())
                        Else

                            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(35) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTableCell())

                        End If
                        _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(45) & _dr(_col.ColumnName).ToString())
                        _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(35) & clsHtmlBuilder.EndTableCell())

                    Next

                    _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(25) & clsHtmlBuilder.EndTableRow())
                Next

                _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(8) & clsHtmlBuilder.EndTable())
            Next
            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(5) & clsHtmlBuilder.AddLineBreak)
            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(2) & clsHtmlBuilder.AddHr())
        Catch ex As Exception
            clsCommon.writeErrorLog("Error in Report Generation", "RuleSet2", "GenerateHtmlReport")
            Throw ex
        End Try
        Return _StrBuil.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```

souce code :

```
 <td nowrap = "nowrap">
         4F0B52DC0001
 </td>
 <td nowrap = "nowrap">
         C006411
 </td>
 <td nowrap = "nowrap">
         Christiansen
 </td>
 <td nowrap = "nowrap">
         Cathy
 </td>
 <td nowrap = "nowrap">
         19570406
 </td>
 <td nowrap = "nowrap">

 </td>
```

Comment: http://www.WhatHaveYouTried.com

Comment: As @Cyborgx37 pointed out, _show us what you have tried_. Point out where your problem is, remove unnecessary code and afterwards you'll note that there is a difference between [StringBuilder.Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append.aspx) and [.AppendLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx)

Comment: in the souce code i want:<td nowrap = "nowrap">this on new line- 4F0B52DC0001 this is on new line-</td>this is n new line- <td nowrap = "nowrap">this is on new line- C006411 this is n new line- </td>....but in last table data there is no value & i want<td nowrap = "nowrap">then this is on new line-</td>........the problem is that in souce code i got: <td nowrap ="nowrap"> one line break then </td>... i donot want the break line in last table data attribute which has no value......in rest which has value there i want break line..... so plz help me buddy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the following?

```xml
<td nowrap = "nowrap">4F0B52DC0001</td>
<td nowrap = "nowrap">C006411</td>
<td nowrap = "nowrap">Christiansen</td>
<td nowrap = "nowrap">Cathy</td>
<td nowrap = "nowrap">19570406</td>
<td nowrap = "nowrap"></td>
```

Try this:

```vb
For Each _col As DataColumn In _Tbl.Columns
    If (Space(45) & _col.ColumnName = "Result") Then
        _StrBuil.Append(Space(35) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTableCell())
    Else
        _StrBuil.Append(Space(35) & clsHtmlBuilder.StartTableCell())
    End If
    _StrBuil.Append(_dr(_col.ColumnName).ToString())
    _StrBuil.AppendLine(clsHtmlBuilder.EndTableCell())
Next
```

(Use Append instead of AppendLine)

If you try asking a clearer question, you may get a more relevant answerer.

---

**EDIT:**
In response to your comment, you can remove the gap between the last (empty) table cell by checking to make sure that the "attribute" value is not blank or null. The line of code that's causing your problems is:

```vb
_StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(45) & _dr(_col.ColumnName).ToString())
```

This will print a line of text (with a new line character at the end) whether or not `_dr(_col.ColumnName)` represents a non-null/non-blank value. Wrap this satement if an if-block that ensures it is only executed if `_dr(_col.ColumnName)` is not null and not blank. You can use `.Trim()` to remove white-space from the value and `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to make sure that there's a non-blank value represented by the string.

---

**EDIT:**
For more information, please see the following links:

- [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)
- [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3)

Think about what you want to accomplish, then write it down as a series of steps (maybe on paper first, then in code). If you cannot do that, then you cannot program (HINT: Almost anyone can program).

Comment: @ruchit - Please let us know if this solved your problem.

Comment: in the souce code i want:<td nowrap = "nowrap">this on new line- 4F0B52DC0001 this is on new line-</td>this is n new line- <td nowrap = "nowrap">this is on new line- C006411 this is n new line- </td>....but in last table data there is no value & i want<td nowrap = "nowrap">then this is on new line-</td>........the problem is that in souce code i got: <td nowrap ="nowrap"> one line break then </td>... i donot want the break line in last table data attribute which has no value......in rest which has value there i want break line..... so plz help me buddy....

Comment: can u tell me what i should put in if conditon so i will get my desierd output.....buddy please help me....i describ the code above so can u give me the exact code with proper if condition by that i can get my desierd output......

Comment: Please read the article I mentioned in my first comment on your question. I have pointed you in the right direction, but as a programmer you owe it to yourself to find the answer on your own. It will build your confidence and enable you to program better in the future.

Comment: (Also, for your information, "buddy" can be perceived as a slightly derogatory name in some locales... for example, mine.)

Comment: if u provide me the code that is very usefull to me,i m new in programming so i dont have more knowledge about it..as a fresher i m not enable to slove it by myself...so please provide me code if possible...????

Comment: please provide me the code it is very use full to me, i m new  in programing....it is very use full to me...please cyborgx37

Comment: thank you cyborgx37......i done it my my self...!!!!!!!by putting  If _dr(_col.ColumnName).ToString().Length > 0 Then
                            _StrBuil.AppendLine(Space(45) & _dr(_col.ColumnName).ToString())
                        End If